# how to include bsd.prog.mk in both GNU and BSD make?

Tags: linux, makefile, freebsd

I am new to the World of makeFile, I have a basic question.

I have a make file with the content.

```
.include <bsd.prog.mk>
```

I am getting the error when executing the make file

```
 Makefile:: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

The reason I am getting the error since I am executing the makefile in the Linux environment instead of the FreeBSD system.

so, Is there any way to include the `bsd.prog.mk` file in both Linux and BSD systems,
if Linux supports it, if not then what is the similar file to include to keep the MakeFile behavior the same.

Comment: Try bmake, which is a port of the NetBSD make tool: https://packages.debian.org/stable/devel/bmake

Answer (score 2):

You need a compatible Make implementation (and build system files). The problem is the default Make implementation on most GNU/Linux systems is GNU Make, which is incompatible with FreeBSD's.

Luckily FreeBSD uses `bmake` nowadays, which is packaged for most systems, if it isn't available in yours, you can download it here:
https://crufty.net/help/sjg/bmake.html (and build it yourself).

Answer (score 1):

You can install bmake on Linux systems and use that, or you can install GNU make on BSD systems and use the GNU make include syntax: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html